# Counting with strings (numbers)

Tags: java, string-parsing

I have a two strings containing a certain number (let's say it is not higher than 10).

```
String five = "5";
String two = "2";
```

How can I add them up together?

```
String seven = five + two;
```

Obviously does not work.

How can I add both numbers to each other and let the output be "7"? Do I have to convert the string first (to an **int** for example)?

Comment: Change String to int?

Comment: @Nfear Seems that is an example.

Comment: @Nfear Just in case counting with int's might be easier

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not an Android question, this is Java question.

```
try {
   String seven = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(five) + Integer.parseInt(two));
} catch (NumberFormatException nfex) {
// one of the strings was not a number
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I changed the tag to "java" to.

Comment: No problem, I just mentioned :) Please if you choose one of the other two answers, take care of the exception!

Comment: I noticed your exception, always usefull! I just have to wait 9 more minutes to except your answer :).

Comment: Nice answer; +1 of course, but the performance degradation cf. pure integer arithmetic cannot be overestimated.

Comment: Slightly shorter:  
String seven = "" + (Integer.parseInt(five) + Integer.parseInt(two));

Answer (score 1):

```
String seven = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(five) + Integer.parseInt(two))
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to convert to int first. Use:

```
String seven = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(five) + Integer.parseInt(two))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int five = 5;
int two = 2;
int seven = five + two;
```

or

```
String five = "5";
String two = "2";
int seven = Integer.parseInt(five) + Integer.parseInt(two);
```

There are various options available.

Comment: Thank you for integrating my suggestion in your answer!